# "clearfix" for position fixed

Tags: css, sass, css-position, web-deployment

*disclaimer: I know that fixed elements are not ment to take theire own space in the flow of a page but i think i need it anyway.*

**Question:**
I try to have my nav in a Grid which has the height of 100vh When I press the trigger element the whole grid slides to the side and reveals the Navigation by adding a class with js. I want the whole viewport container to be in a fixed position but as I set it to `position: fixed;` all of the content below will overflow the container as it should by default behavior.
is there a way to "clearfix" this overflow?

I aswell want to hide it again with a `"onscroll"` event, so just changing the backgroundcolor is no option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to change the overflow permission in the container with something like:

```
someDiv{
<!---Your nav should be wrapped with this-->
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Then, add an onClick to your nav so when the nav is accessed, the overflow is changed

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').onclick = function(){
document.getElementById('someDiv').style.overflow = 'visible';
}
```

Not quite sure if this is what you are after.

Comment: thx for your answer but its not quite what i looked for. I found a solution which works for me with not even using `position: fixed`.